# embedded mongodb not starting with springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

While following a tutorial, I am using SPRING INITIALIZR https://start.spring.io/ to generate a project with reactiveMongoDB using springboot 2.0.2.

The gradle file lists:
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')

I was able to import the project into eclipse, and the main class is using autoconfiguration.

The problem is that upon startup, I see the following (for some reason there are two log entries)

> 2018-05-25 13:26:29.624  INFO 4300 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
>   2018-05-25 13:26:30.093  INFO 4300 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}

but later, it fails to connect:

> Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017

Using a network tool, I see that the server never started up? I do not have a firewall running.

Can anyone suggest ways to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - needed to add "Embedded MongoDB" to the list of packages.

Comment: How did you figured that out?

Comment: Well, it seemed like the app was attempting to connect to a mongoDB server on a particular TCP port, and no such server has been started. I then tried adding the embedded MongoDB package, and the error went away. The book I am reading did not state that adding this package was necessary however. Perhaps things have changed since the book was written?

Comment: What package you mean, ? can you explain mrore ?